# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure in .net core 3.0

Tags: iis, .net-core-3.0

how to solve HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure in .net core 3.0 while running with IIS

Comment: Check if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699234/asp-net-core-3-0-http-error-502-5-process-failure

Comment: What error message did you see in event viewer? Besides, please post your IIS configuration.